# Phonegap camera.getPicture - no callback on first call

Tags: cordova

I'm using Phonegap 2.7.0 on iPhone 4S. When I first call `.getPicture`, no callback is fired after selecting a picture from library. After that, everything is fine, until the app is restarted. My code:

```
var captureSuccess = function (imageURI) {
    alert('Success');
};

var captureError = function (error) {
    alert('Error');
};

navigator.camera.getPicture(captureSuccess, captureError, {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
});
```

When I use `DATA_URL` as `sourceType` callbacks are fired every time.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you found how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using click event of a button to call `getPicture`. Returning false on click solved my problem. Not sure why, though.

Comment: Good find. Regarding the reason for that, it was because since you where not returning false, the click event was reloading the entire app (window.location set to blank)

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and solved it. Because you import two "cordova.js" in your app, and maybe one is in the iframe. you can use "parent.cordova" in iframe instead.